# Close bus in python-can

Tags: python, can-bus, python-can

I am using `python-can` to send CAN messages like this:

```
import can

bus2 = can.interface.Bus(bustype='pcan', channel='PCAN_USBBUS1', bitrate=500000)

msg = can.Message(
    arbitration_id=0x42, data=[0, 25, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1], is_extended_id=False
)

bus2.send(msg)
```

The script works fine, but when I run it for a 2nd time, it results in an error, because the bus is still open from the previous time.
I think I need something like this at the end of my script:

```
bus2.close()
```

However, this does not exist and I can't seem to find the proper way to do it in the `python-can` documentation. How can I properly close the bus in order to be able to use it again the next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Bus` object should be used inside a `with` statement to be closed properly.

```
import can
with can.interface.Bus(bustype='pcan', channel='PCAN_USBBUS1', bitrate=500000) as bus2:
    msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x42, data=[0, 25, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1], is_extended_id=False)
    bus2.send(msg)
```

You should be able to send more messages inside this open block, but after this block the bus will be closed properly

[See the docs](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Comment: Thanks! The importance of using it inside a `with` statement was not getting through to me when I read the docs.

Answer (score 1):

There is reference to shutdown [in the python-can doc here](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/bus.html).  This works for me under Windows.  There is a noticeable delay when you call it, at least with the Ixxat CAN interface that I'm using.

```
# Open the interface
bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='ixxat', ...)
.
.
.
# Close the interface
bus.shutdown()
```